# Determine the minimum possible amount of distinct prime divisors of $19^{4n}+4$

Tags: number-theory

Determine the minimum possible amount of distinct prime divisors of $19^{4n}+4$, for a positive integer $n$

My works:

By the Sophie Germain factorization, we have
$$19^{4n}+4=(19^{2n}-2\cdot 19^n+2)(19^{2n}+2\cdot 19^n+2)$$

this problem answer is $3$,can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$19^{4n}+4$ has at least 3 prime factors:**

Write $19^{4n}+4=xy$ using your factorization. Observe that $x,y$ are relatively prime, since they are both odd and their difference is $4\cdot 19^n$. Moreover, modulo 5 we have $19^{4n}=(-1)^{4n}=1$, so $5\ | \ 19^{4n}+4$. Since neither factor is a power of 5 (see below), the result follows.

Taking $n=1$ yields $19^4+4=5^2\cdot 13\cdot 401$ has 3 distinct prime factors, attaining the minimum.

**Silly short proof that neither factor is a power of 5:**

Both factors are one more than a perfect square, so by [Mihailescu's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) they are not powers of 5.

Comment: Hello,why can't divisor $5^2$?

Comment: It can. There's no problem if $5$ divides it with a higher power, because you asked for the number of distinct prime factors.

Comment: this case maybe $5^k|x?$,or $5^k|y,k\ge 2$,that's maybe only have two distinct prime factors?

Comment: No, because you know that $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime, so they don't share any prime factors. In particular, if one is divisible by 5 then the other is not.

Comment: because if $5^k=x$,then $y$ have only prime factots,that's mean have only two prime factors

Comment: I have read it,because I think this case,you can't explain: why can't $19^{4n}+4$ only have two prime factors? in other words,why $x=5^k,y=p'$ can't it?

Comment: I added a proof to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

$19^{4n} + 4 = (19^{4n} - 1) + 5 = 0 \pmod 5$